# C++ Conventions: Structure of Headers and Classes

Tags: c++, coding-style, conventions

Well, this is a pretty trivial question. But i'd like to know if it is okay to put multiple classes into one header / source file. I've often enough seen that for every class there is another header and another source file, like it is in Java (not only by Convention...)

I see the ups and downs here: on the one hand you might want to have some relevant classes on one place for editing, since big projects sometimes require you to search a bit for them. On the other hand, more files make single files less heavy, so you don't have to scroll down tousands of lines to get to the method you're searching.

Now what do the Conventions say about that?

[Example]

At the moment i have 3 classes in one file: a Server, A ClientHandler for the Server and a ServerManager.
The server manages the connections, the ClientHandler manages all in- and outgoing traffic for each client and the ServerManager contains some logic i need to run the Server.

[Edit] be gentle with my abilities of the english language, i'm foreign ;)

Comment: It's common to place each object class in its own files, and only file which may hold more classes / structs is like a toolbox class (for example in geometry a class holding functions for circles, rectangles, etc). Its like with functions, when you need more than one sentence what a function does, split it. If you have a file with classes, and you need multiple sections to describe what it does, split the file.

Comment: "common" is an easy thing to say. The problem here is, i'd like to know if someone would say "that's fck*d up code" if i show it...

Comment: @Manhattan, !@#$ would be the appropriate response, if the project is big enough. It is good form to put each class in it's own files.

Comment: i added a little example to understand what i'm doing

Comment: If a class depends on some helper classes which aren't relevant to other classes, I put them wholly in the source file in an unnamed namespace if I can.

Comment: It's worth remembering that you can have header guards as they are called `#ifndef __myfile` then `#define __myfile` code here `#endif` that way you can include your file (you can write `#include "myfile.h"` as many times as you like, this often helps IDEs which do not realise that the file you are working on is an include itself and stuff. You probably knew this but header guards work :) No penalty exists in using them, provided the name is unique, typically __FILE_NAME_H_ is the structure.

Comment: @AlecTeal header guards are standard practice. Unless the poster is confused about it, there's usually no need to suggest them.

Comment: @NeilKirk I'm sorry then, when I first started many moons ago I wanted stuff in several files but found I had problems and I don't really like forward declarations, sorry about that.

Comment: @AlecTeal well the guards are clear (tough this is something you could actually answer me: isn't `#ifndef`/`#define` outdated to `#pragma once` ?)

Comment: @Mr.Manhattan #pragma means "attention compiler I want to tell you something" like OpenMP instructions and stuff, so it's not guaranteed to work everywhere, like.... wx.h (header for wxWidgets) has a lot of typedefs I don't actually use in my code, when I compile with gcc I use -wall and -wextra as anyone should, so I get a lot of warnings about unused typedefs I use http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html those pragmas, the code is still portable, but GCC now knows what I mean, `#pragma once` may be obeyed by GCC, but it's unlikely to be standard as it fills no dying need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's considered good form for each class to have its own header/implementation pair.

The most compelling reason (for me) is that the files are named after the class they contain. This makes it easy to find the correct file for a declaration in the code. If a file has more than one type in it, it becomes harder to name, and therefore harder to maintain.

However, sometimes it's not so clear cut. A "main" class might have some other supporting class that's definitely part of its interface (in the Herb Sutter sense of interface), but doesn't rightly belong as a nested type. This should be rare, but such a case might justify having more than one class per file.

If you've gone to the trouble of abstracting out concepts (such as in the example you give), why not go the extra little bit and put them in their own files? You **will** thank yourself for it down the line!

Comment: i think you're right, i'll do that

Comment: And what do you do about free functions?  Whether it's good form or not depends on the class; on the application I'm currently working on, about 2/3 of the classes aren't defined in headers at all, but in source files.  And the visitor or observer interface should be defined in the same header as what it visits or obsserves.

Comment: I tend to name the files after the abstractions they represent, and in C++ (and C#, too) that means the name of the class. In C++, the free-functions that belong to the *interface* (as I said) are co-located as belonging to that same abstraction. Classes defined in source are (IME, anyway) helpers rather than abstractions, so need a different mindset in any case. I agree with you, BTW- not a rule :)

Answer (score 1):

There's no real rule, other than common sense.  If two classes
are closely linked, it's common to put them in the same header.
And of course, not everything in C++ is a class; free functions
may be grouped in various different headers according to
whatever seems most logical.

Also, there isn't always a one-to-one relationship between
headers and source files.  If your class is a template, there
may not be a source file at all.  On the other hand, if you're
writing a library that will be widely used, and the class isn't
polymorphic, you'll probably want to put each function in
a separate source file.

And a lot of classes are defined directly in source files, and not in headers.

Comment: On a related note, I was working on this project which had a very big class with lots of image processing. I had inherited the code, and the guts of the class was a single, massive method, to the tune of about a dozen screenfulls. I ended up splitting that function into numerous functions implemented in numerous files. This split increased readability, testability, and decreased the debug-build-test cycle because the compiler had a lot less compiling to do after each small change. This just seemed like common sense to me; wasn't following some special rule.

Comment: @SchighSchagh Exactly.  Common sense is the best rule here.  (But also, keep classes and functions small, so that you can split them up.)